# How can I call a method from a powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, methods

I'm trying to obtain information that Microsoft says I get by running the following command:

`IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo::GetInfo`

The problem is, I don't know how to run this command in powershell.  I get the following error message when trying to run it this way:

```
[Microsoft.Update.IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo]::GetIno

Unable to find type [Microsoft.Update.IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo]: make sure that the assembly containing this type is 
loaded.
At line:1 char:1
+ [Microsoft.Update.IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo]::GetInfo
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Microsoft.Update.IWindowsUpdateAgentInfo:TypeName) [], RuntimeExcep 
   tion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For a start, what you have there seems to be an interface (from the name). Interfaces have neither static methods nor can they be instantiated

Comment: Yeah I thought that was weird to, but this article (step 5) says to do this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387285%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is a comobject, try this:

```
[version](New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AgentInfo).            
GetInfo('ProductVersionString')
```